# Displaying a DIV larger than its parent DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css, submenu

I have 2 DIVs  that I want to display on the **same row** (one on the left, the other on the right).

The left div:

```
.leftdiv {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width : 30%;
}
```

The right one:

```
.right-div {
    float : right;
    width : 40%;
    background-color: lime;
}
```

The left DIV wraps 2 other DIVs: `dropdown-content` that is displayed after the clicking on `dropdiv`.

I want `dropdown-content` to take half (50%) of the page but even when I set its width to 100% I can not get it larger than its parent `leftdiv` (which must not exceed 30% of the page).

How to fix this?

[**JS Bin**](https://jsbin.com/yuduzoh/edit?html,css,js,output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it 50vw (50% of viewport width).

Comment: Thank you. It works on FF and Chrome. Do you think it is cross browsers?

Comment: Great tool for browser support information - http://caniuse.com/#search=viewport To answer your question, it should work on IE9+

Answer (score 2):

Remove `position:relative;` from `.leftdiv` and set `width: 50%;` on `.dropdown-content`

I think it should work in every browser

Comment: Very clever. Thank you very much. (+1 but I accepted the other answer even if yours is equally very interesting. Thank you again) .